# How to filter JSON data based on attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON data.

```
{
  "partners": [
    {
      "logo": "school-of-bookkeeping.png",
      "title": "Schoolofbook<br class='d-none d-md-inline-block'/>keeping.com",
      "websiteURL":"https://www.schoolofbookkeeping.com",
      "getInTouchURL":"https://www.schoolofbookkeeping.com",
      "location":"Santa Monical, CA, US",
      "servicesCategories":["Consulting Services","Webgility Setup"],
      "accountingSoftware":["QuickBooks Online","QuickBooks Enterprise","QuickBooks Point of Sale"],
      "onlineStore":["Magento","Shopify","WooCommerce"],
      "marketplace":["Amazon","eBay","Etsy"],
      "description": "Teaching Businesses and Accounting Professionals the ins and outs of ecommerce.",
      "longDescription":"<p class='fs-16 lh-1-5'>Let's face it; ecommerce is hard. From tracking inventory, sales tax requirements, shipping fulfillment, and general bookkeeping, keeping pace with all the requirements and business workflows is difficult. That's why we have partnered with Webgility to create a learning resource to provide small and medium-sized businesses a seamless and path from setup to implementation, so the accounting is done so that can focus on running your business, rather than your business, rather than running yourself ragged.</p><p class='fs-16 lh-1-5'>Our lifelong learners are here for hire so you can be set up for success and have a trusted advisor to guide you through setup to implementation.</p>",
      "servicesWeProvide": "<p class='fs-16 lh-1-5'>Website creation to e-commerce implementation.</p>",
      "featured": false,
      "partnerType": "Certified",
      "link": "school-of-bookkeeping",
      "customClass": "school-of-bookkeeping"
    },
    {
      "logo": "danwidth.png",
      "title": "Danwidth",
      "websiteURL":"https://www.danwidth.com",
      "getInTouchURL":"https://completebusinessgroup.com/danwidth/",
      "location":"Tucson, AZ, US",
      "servicesCategories":["Consulting Services","Webgility Setup"],
      "accountingSoftware":["QuickBooks Online","QuickBooks Enterprise","QuickBooks Point of Sale"],
      "onlineStore":["Magento","Shopify","WooCommerce"],
      "marketplace":["Amazon","eBay","Etsy"],
      "description": "Put your ecommerce bookkeeping on cruise control.",
      "longDescription":"<p class='fs-16 lh-1-5'>I don't want to be your bookkeeper. I transform businesses through technology by creating automagic workflows that allow your bookkeeping to be handled \"by accident.\" Imagine entering data once, or not at all, and your bookkeeping is done for you. Specializing in brick and mortar retail and ecommerce, I will set up your services to integrate so that your accounting and bookkeeping is done for you as a result of you simply running your business. We work with a host of solution providers that all integrate into your accounting platform that will enable you to make informed business decisions in real-time.</p><p class='fs-16 lh-1-5'>My expertise is unparalleled across all of Intuit's Small business platforms. Online or Desktop, including Point of Sale, if it can be done in QuickBooks, I know how to make it happen. In addition, we partner with other business services to increase your revenue, decrease your expenses, and widen your online presence.</p>",
      "servicesWeProvide": "<p class='fs-16 lh-1-5'>End-to-end services from website creation, digital marketing, ecommerce platform to bookkeeping, payroll service setup, and support.</p>",
      "featured": false,
      "partnerType": "Certified",
      "link": "danwidth",
      "customClass": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I filter this on the basis of servicesCategories, accountingSoftware, onlineStore, marketplace, and partnerType?

I want to filter data with $.getJSON() method with on change select box value.

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Show what you have tried and where you are stuck. When practical post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you want to go about filtering. There are a few different ways to accomplish this, here is one function that allows you to pass in the key you want to filter on and an array of values to filter by:

```js
let filterBy = (list, keyToFilter, filters) => {
  // Allow a string to be passed in
  if(!Array.isArray(filters)) filters = [filters];

  return list.filter(item => {
    let values = item[keyToFilter];
    // Check if the filter exists
    if(!values) return false;

    // For items that aren't arrays, like partnerType
    //  This makes it compatible with the conditional
    //  below, where the logic for check happens.
    if(!Array.isArray(values)) values = [values];
    
    // Check if array of your filters matches any in list
    return filters.some(n => values.includes(n));
   }
  );
};
```

Then you can call this on your list like so:

```js
let list = { "partners": [
  ...
]};

let accountingSoftware = filterBy(list["partners"], "accountingSoftware", ["QuickBooks Online","QuickBooks Enterprise"]);

let partnerType = filterBy(list["partners"], "partnerType", "Certified");
```

Here is an example if you want to play around with it more, https://repl.it/@BenjaminKnox/filter-json